# Conditional math operations with columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of columns in my dataframe with different values, as seen in this sample:

```py
Especies  Especies_0  Especies_1  Especies_2  Especies_3
2.20        3.44        1.90        1.24        0.00
2.20        3.04        2.55        0.00        0.00
1.88        2.19        0.00        0.00        0.00
2.20        3.44        2.28        2.55        0.00
3.44        2.20        0.00        0.00        0.00
2.20        2.58        0.00        0.00        0.00
1.88        2.19        0.00        0.00        0.00
3.44        1.91        3.04        1.83        3.98
3.44        2.20        0.00        0.00        0.00
2.20        2.55        1.90        0.00        0.00
1.88        2.20        0.00        0.00        0.00
```

The operation i want to perform is:

`avg(abs(max - col) for col in cols)`

where max is the maximum value of the columns in each row (for example, for the first row, max would be 3.44 and cols is the rest of the values in the columns), abs is the absolute function and avg means taking the average.

For example, for the first row, the operation would be: `((3.44-2.20)+(3.44-1.90)+(3.44-1.24))/3 = 1.66`

and for the 5th row, with values `(3.44, 2.20, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00)` the result would be: `(3.44 -2.20) /1 = 1.24`

This is simple enough, but there's a catch, I don't want to consider the column of the max value, or any columns with 0.0 in them (take into account that the max value column changes, it's not always the same as do the number of columns with 0.0 in them).

I have managed to do it with single, scalar values, I even did a function that does that

```py
def ele_diff(esp0, esp1, esp2, esp3, esp4):
    species = sorted([esp0, esp1, esp2, esp3, esp4])
    diff = [species[-1] - spec for spec in species if spec != 0.0 and spec !=species[-1]]
    return (sum(diff)/len(diff))
```

But I'm not able to apply my function to the dataframe. I've tried [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [df.applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), but they don't seem to work with the function I've made (applymap considers only 1 input and 1 output, while apply does not feed the function with each row separatedly, so the function returns ValueError because the truth value of a series is ambiguous).

I've also tried to do it directly with the dataframe, but as it's got complex logic, I haven't been able to come with a solution.

The main problem I've faced seems to be with checking that the values I'm going to substract are not 0.0 or the maximum.

Comment: What will be the average of 5th row ? Is it  2.20 ?

Comment: in case there are only 2 columns with values other than 0.0, then it's just the substraction.
In the case of the 5th row, with values (3.44,  2.20 , 0.0,  0.00,  0.00) the result would be 3.44-2.20 = (3.44-2.20)/1 = 1.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First filter only necessary columns by starts substring `Especies` in [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), set missing values for maximal and `0` values, subtract maximal, convert to absolute values and last get average:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='^Especies')

#or if necessary specify columns names in list
#cols = ['Especies', 'Especies_0', 'Especies_1', 'Especies_2', 'Especies_3']
#df1 = df[cols]

max1 = df1.max(axis=1)
mask = df1.ne(max1, axis=0) & df1.ne(0)
df['new'] = df1.where(mask).sub(max1, axis=0).abs().mean(axis=1)
print (df)
    Especies  Especies_0  Especies_1  Especies_2  Especies_3       new
0       2.20        3.44        1.90        1.24        0.00  1.660000
1       2.20        3.04        2.55        0.00        0.00  0.665000
2       1.88        2.19        0.00        0.00        0.00  0.310000
3       2.20        3.44        2.28        2.55        0.00  1.096667
4       3.44        2.20        0.00        0.00        0.00  1.240000
5       2.20        2.58        0.00        0.00        0.00  0.380000
6       1.88        2.19        0.00        0.00        0.00  0.310000
7       3.44        1.91        3.04        1.83        3.98  1.425000
8       3.44        2.20        0.00        0.00        0.00  1.240000
9       2.20        2.55        1.90        0.00        0.00  0.500000
10      1.88        2.20        0.00        0.00        0.00  0.320000
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1.where(mask))
    Especies  Especies_0  Especies_1  Especies_2  Especies_3
0       2.20         NaN        1.90        1.24         NaN
1       2.20         NaN        2.55         NaN         NaN
2       1.88         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3       2.20         NaN        2.28        2.55         NaN
4        NaN        2.20         NaN         NaN         NaN
5       2.20         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
6       1.88         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
7       3.44        1.91        3.04        1.83         NaN
8        NaN        2.20         NaN         NaN         NaN
9       2.20         NaN        1.90         NaN         NaN
10      1.88         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

---

```
print (df1.where(mask).sub(max1, axis=0))
    Especies  Especies_0  Especies_1  Especies_2  Especies_3
0      -1.24         NaN       -1.54       -2.20         NaN
1      -0.84         NaN       -0.49         NaN         NaN
2      -0.31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3      -1.24         NaN       -1.16       -0.89         NaN
4        NaN       -1.24         NaN         NaN         NaN
5      -0.38         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
6      -0.31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
7      -0.54       -2.07       -0.94       -2.15         NaN
8        NaN       -1.24         NaN         NaN         NaN
9      -0.35         NaN       -0.65         NaN         NaN
10     -0.32         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Can you explain how that works? I've tried it and I've gotten weird results, orders of magnitude over the expected values (308, for example) when the expected value should be in the same order of magnitude of the original values.

Comment: Is it possible that it's taking every column? I do have more columns in the dataframe that I'm not using right now...

Comment: It seems it was taking every column, Ive solved it by selecting only the important columns